# Делать статичные методы, "лишь бы не создавать экземпляр класса" - верный ли это подход?

Tags: java, android

Я пытаюсь понять, как правильно писать код.

Я всегда когда это возможно, делаю статичные методы для выполнения какой либо задачи. Т.е. статичных методов довольно много.

Я не гуру и не профи Java. Я ее изучаю. Мне как то на курсах сказали, что статик методы и абстрактные классы необходимо использовать с умом.

Т.е. моя мотивация при создании статик методов, "лишь бы не создавать экземпляр класса" - верный ли это подход, если нет был бы рад получить ответ почему нет. Спасибо!

Comment: "Мне как то на курсах сказали, что ... необходимо использовать с умом." - Вам повезло, Вы попали на прекрасные курсы.

Comment: Это были курсы Epam в Караганде, Казахстан. Но не прошел, т.к. английский сильно хромает.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Статические и нестатические методы отличаются (главным образом) только наличием одной вещи - контекстом. Если код суммирует два аргумента (пресловутый Math) или преобразовывает массив в список (`Arrays.asList()`), то ему не нужен для этого внешний контекст (состояние), и такой код, по логике, должен быть статическим. В случаях, когда вызов метода меняет состояние, и без экземпляра класса не обойтись (например, добавление новой секции к отчету), код, конечно, не должен быть статическим, и метод `ReportSectionAppender.append(Report report, ReportSection section)` без дополнительных условий появляться не должен.

Однако лично у меня есть сильные предубеждения против статических вызовов, из-за которых *лично я* этой логике не следую. Статические вызовы облегчают написание кода, но у них есть два минуса, которые (*лично для меня*) перевешивают плюсы. Во-первых, статические вызовы скрывают зависимости и вносят небольшую долю глобального контекста в код - в конструктор класса может передаваться три объекта, а внутри использоваться еще с десяток статических классов, что обнаружится только в тот момент, когда на рефакторинг будет дан зеленый свет, "потому что этот класс почти не затрагивает другие". И, во-вторых, это довольно жесткий хардкод - статический вызов сам по себе нельзя ни подменить другой реализацией, ни обернуть в прокси, не изменив сам код. В случае того же самого рефакторинга это может встать серьезным боком, если архитектура не была продумана идеально изначально (это как раз мой случай).

Что по поводу "лишь бы не создавать экземпляр класса" - это обычные опасения, от которых стоит избавляться. Когда вы пишете программу, ваша первая задача - реализовать поставленные к ней требования, оптимизацией - если она вообще потребуется - можно будет заняться позже. Делайте так, как удобно.

Резюмируя: писать бесконтекстные методы статикой и выносить их в utility-классы - это обычная практика, принятая коммьюнити. Тем не менее, у этого подхода есть минусы, которые заставляют некоторых ее не использовать или использовать по минимуму.

Comment: Согласен. Можно ещё добавить про неудобство юнит-тестирования - приходится добавлять много костылей, чтобы подменить статический метод.

Answer (score 17):

При использовании `static` нужно быть внимательным к тому где и как вы его используете.

Так как `static`, фактически, означает, что этот объект *singleton*, т.е. он (класс) и его поля существуют в единственном экземпляре, и используя его в других классах вы используете один и тот же объект, а изменяя его состояние, к примеру, в классе N, вы изменяете его и для остальных классов.

Зачастую их используют как `util-ные` классы, к примеру когда вам нужно в каком то месте в коде произвести подсчет, или конвертацию какого то значения. Хороший пример [java.lang.Math](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html), класс который используется для математических операции.

Либо как объект который содержит в себе значения которые могут быть нужны и являются общими для остальных классов, к примеру это могут быть какие то константы которые могут использовать остальные классы из этого приложения. И чтобы каждый раз не создавать объект который содержит всегда одинаковую информацию - создают его один для всех.

**Пример:**

```
double x = Math.sqrt(81);
```

быстро, не создавая экземпляр выполнили операцию вычитания квадратного корня.

P.S. по поводу создания новых объектов: иногда лучше создать новый объект и быть уверенным что в данный момент этот экземпляр больше нигде не используется и не изменяется.

Comment: В ответе упущен случай статического метода в нестатическом классе, или в джаве так нельзя?

Comment: @andreymal Возможно Вы об этом говорите http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: "В ответе упущен случай статического метода в нестатическом классе, или в джаве так нельзя?" В джаве нет такого понятия статический класс (не считая внутренних статических классов, но у них совсем другой смысл). Поэтому любой статического метод находится либо в нестатическом классе, либо в интерфейсе (но это скорее костыль, чем обычная практика)

Answer (score 12):

Мое мнение:

1. для приватных методов класса, если можно сделать метод статически -
   обязательно делайте его статическим, это покажет всем что метод не
   связан с контекстом класса и его можно вынести в другой класс или
   легко рефакторить.
2. для публичным методов класса - используйте `static` очень
   ограниченно:

   - во-первых, лучше если `static` методы будут находится в отдельных
     Utils классах. Не стоит смешивать в одном классе статические и
     обычные методы
   - во-вторых, статические публичные методы лучше использовать только для методов, которые делают простые операции одним единственным способом. Например, такие как взятие синуса, округление и т.п.
   - в-третьих, никогда не используйте статические методы если возможно потребуется их расширение на разные сущности или разные виды реализации. Например, если вы делаете методы parseXML(url), parseTxt(url), parseHTML(url), которые делают похожие вещи но с разными источниками намного лучше создать интерфейс, имеющий метод parse(url) и три класса XmlPraser, TxtPraser и HTMLParser, которые реализуют этот метод. Это упростит понимание и позволит потом легко и просто добавить четвертый и пятый источник.
3. Чтобы избавится от необходимости "создавать экземпляр класса" советую посмотреть на dependency injection фреймворки, такие как Spring или guice. Они позволяют легко и незаметно "создавать экземпляры класса", например сравните:

код с использованием DI

```
public class myClass {
   @Inject Parser parser;

   public void myMethod() {
       parser.parser(url);
   }
```

код с использованием статических методов

```
public class myClass {

   public void myMethod() {
       Parser.parser(url);
   }
```

Не такая большая разница, не так ли? При этом, при использовании DI вы сохраните гибкость, возможность переопределения при Unit тестировании, легкость расширения и т.п.

Comment: во втором примере класса, что указывает на то, что этот метод `static`?

Answer (score -4):

Нет, это ужасный принцип. Статичные блоки, без объектов - это функциональное програмирование в его худшем проявлении.
Хороший код - это код, который можно легко протестировать, рефакторизировать и расширить - SOLID принцип.
Если вы пишите много приватных статичных методов (как тут <s>говноко</s> специалисты советуют), то вы в 80% случаев "пишите велосипеды" и эти утилитарные методы к 2016 году до вас уже 33 раза написали.
Посмотрите на библиотеки от Apache Foundation и Guava от гугла - там вменяемые разработчики для вас уже все подобное написали.

Comment: "это функциональное програмирование" - вы так пишите как будто функциональное программирование это что-то однозначно плохое, хотя как раз оно сейчас в моде (не путать с процедурным программированием). Конечно, функциональное программирование не серебряная пуля, как некоторые считают, но и не абсолютное зло.

Comment: Цель ООП - ясность и читаемость, т. к. программа должна отображать реальный мир (что из этого у большинства получается - это уже 5-ое, 10-ое). А теперь попробуйте крупное приложение сформулировать в терминах функционального приложения и любой разработчик, который должен будет ваш код через 5 лет в продакшене поддерживать и расширять, найдет вас и убьет, причем самым жестоким способом.

Comment: Нахожу крайне забавным, что PHP тендирует все время в сторону строгости и ООП (из функционального мира) - там все уже этой свободой наелись до сыта. А Java со всеми Groovie и Scala наоборот прут в сторону функциональности - ветер свободы булки щекочет.

Comment: Вы не понимаете разницы между императивно-процедурным и декларативно-функциональным программированием. PHP никогда не поддерживал полноценного декларативно-функционального программирования.

Comment: Языки функционального программирования Scala, Clojure, Лисп, Haskell, XSLT (условно) и да, на них вполне пишут крупные и даже огромные приложения.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35974/discussion-between-webaib-and-viacheslav-vedenin).

Comment: @webair Советы предпочитать статические функции публичным это жесть. Награжу ваш адекватный ответ чтобы он выделялся.