# Зачем использовать статические методы и как их использовать?

Tags: java, ооп

Не понимаю, какой в них смысл.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Делать статичные методы, "лишь бы не создавать экземпляр класса" - верный ли это подход?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/494788/%d0%94%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8b-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%88%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d0%b7%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be)

Comment: Для этого надо сначала понять [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1320317/204920).

Answer (score 0):

Статические методы в программировании предоставляют функциональность, которая не зависит от конкретного экземпляра класса. Они являются частью самого класса, а не его экземпляров, и могут быть вызваны непосредственно через имя класса, без необходимости создания объекта этого класса.

Я могу привести в пример 3 случая, когда это приемлимо или необходимо использовать

1. Утилитарные функции: Если у вас есть некоторая функциональность, которая не зависит от состояния объекта и может быть использована во всей программе, статические методы могут быть хорошим выбором. Примером может служить математический класс, содержащий методы для расчетов, такие как вычисление квадратного корня или округления числа
2. Фабричные методы: Статические методы могут использоваться для создания экземпляров классов. Это может быть полезно, если создание объекта требует сложной логики или дополнительных проверок. Например, у вас может быть класс "Автомобиль", а статический метод "createCar()", который будет создавать объекты класса "Автомобиль" с заданными параметрами и возвращать их. Для лучшего понимания фабричных методов почитайте о патерне "Фабрика"
3. Доступ к общим ресурсам: Если у вас есть ресурсы или данные, которые должны быть доступны всем экземплярам класса, вы можете использовать статические методы для обеспечения доступа к ним. Например, у вас может быть статический метод "getDatabaseConnection()", который будет возвращать единственное соединение с базой данных для всей программы

Пишется статический метод во всех языках примерно так:

```
Класс ClassName{
   public static void StaticMethod(){
   ...
   }
}
```

Также, упомяну, что статические методы не могут обращаться к нестатическим полям. Необходимо это учитывать при конструировании программы

Статика работает только со статикой

И помните, что статические методы - это скорее исключение. Не стоит их вставлять везде, где можно - это плохой тон

Comment: Вопрос вообще был не о том как использовать статические методы, а в чем смысл.

Comment: Примерно так - `public static void StaticMethod() ...` - ну-ну. Кстати, именно ключевое слово `class`, которое стоит на месте вашего `Класс` практически во всех языках одинаковое, а вот остальное - нет.